# Resizing images using imagemagick in node.js

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

In my application i tried to resize the image using imagemagick but i got following error error while resizing: imagesexecvp(): No such file or directory.this is my code

```
   im.resize({
  srcPath:  '/tmp/Images/' + req.files.image.name,
  dstPath: 'resized_'+req.files.image.name ,
  width:42,
  height:42
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) {

      console.log('error while resizing images' + stderr);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imagemagick module uses the `convert` and `identify` commands and the error you describe could happen because the commands can't be found. Make sure the commands are in a folder referenced by the path environment variable or, alternatively you can reference the commands in you node application:

```
var im = require('imagemagick');    
im.identify.path = '/opt/ImageMagick/bin/identify'
im.convert.path = '/opt/ImageMagick/bin/convert';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to resize the file without changing the destination.  Try this:

```
im.resize({
  srcPath:  process.cwd() + '/tmp/Images/' + req.files.image.name,
  dstPath:  process.cwd() + '/tmp/Images/resized_'+req.files.image.name ,
  width:42,
  height:42
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) {
      console.log('error while resizing images' + stderr);
  };
  console.log( process.cwd() + '/tmp/Images/' + req.files.image.name + 'has been resized and saved as ' + process.cwd() + '/tmp/Images/resized_'+req.files.image.name)
});
```

You might also check your permissions (ls -l) in `/tmp/Images/` to make sure they are set properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to install image magic command line tools. Try `brew install imagemagick`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ubuntu, install package like this:

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

After that, try again :D